# Copy text of a PDF file to an NSString

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics

I want to copy the text of an embedded PDF file in my project to an `NSString`.
I tried [Zachron's pdfiphone](https://github.com/zachron/pdfiphone) but it doesn't seem to be working on armv7. I need it to work on armv7.

I've read some the Quartz framework guide, but I still don't know how to get the text of a PDF using Quartz. If you know the solution, with Quartz or not, please write it down.

Comment: I mean by saying "text of PDF" is that an ebook includes just text (no images, no links etc.) as content.

Answer (score 0):

If your target PDF is not written in CJK(Chinese,Japanese and Korean), your way is simpler one.

1. Download PDFKitten. It has a sample PDF parser.
2. Integrate PDFCore part of PDFKitten into your project. Please note that PDFKitten is pre ARC code. So you have to set -fno-objc-arc to all PDFKitten files.
3. In PDF, printing text operators are TJ and Tj.
4. So you have to modify call back functions for TJ and Tj.

If you have to handle CJK PDF file, your way is more complicated. Because many CJK PDF file has CID encoding. CID means character identification for glyph. PDFKitten does not cover such handling. You have to add CID to UCS2 conversion function.